# How to setup a domain name on my EC2 server

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, amazon-ec2, domain

I bought a domain from whois.com and I am trying to set it up on my Amazon EC2 instance. I have Apache installed on it.

I saw these two related questions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/117413/setup-domain-with-amazon-ec2) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/137824/amazon-ec2-assign-domain-name) but could still use some hand holding given this is my first time trying to set it up.

Would be great to have some links that shows a step by step approach to setting it up from what to do on whois.com to the right config on Apache.

So far, I have created an Elastic IP and have it set under A Records for both my www.example.com and example.com domains to use.

It's not working, not sure what the next steps are? I haven't made any changes to my httpd.conf yet.

BTW, I am still not very familiar with all the sys admin jargon so go slow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fault. I didn't associate my instance with the elastic IP from the AWS dashboard. Problem solved!